# Search for a specific string in an SQLite database - Android SDK

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm using an SQLite database in Android SDK and I know this is a very simple question but I have the following function below. I'm trying to search for if a username is within the SQL database but I cant think of how I would structure the query.

What would be the proper way to search for the if the string "user" is within the table "ACCOUNT_TABLE"

```
public boolean isUser(String user){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String queryString = "SELECT " + COLUMN_USERNAME + " FROM " + ACCOUNT_TABLE + " WHERE " (???);

        db.close();
        /*if(found in database) 
            return true;
        else 
            return false;*/
    }
```

Comment: I am neither proficient with SQL lite, nor Java, but I noticed that you didn't specify a column in your "WHERE" clause. Also, I would strongly recommend to use prepared statement instead of raw SQL, to protect yourself against SQL injection. There seems to be a nice tutorial here : https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/select/

Comment: yeah I planned on reformatting it later using query parameters. I just didnt know how to get it for the time being. I'll check out the link tho, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is with the `rawQuery()` method, which takes 2 arguments:

1. the sql `SELECT` statement with `?` placeholders for the parameters that you want to pass
2. a `String` array containing all the values for the parameters of the sql statement, in the order they appear in the
   statement

`rawQuery()` returns a `Cursor` which you can check if it contains any rows and if it does this means that the `user` you search for exists in the table:

```
public boolean isUser(String user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String queryString = "SELECT 1 FROM " + ACCOUNT_TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_USERNAME + " = ?";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(queryString, new String[]{user});
    boolean result = c.getCount() > 0;
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't call db.close() this is bad for performance

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

String queryString = "SELECT " + COLUMN_USERNAME + " FROM " + ACCOUNT_TABLE + " WHERE COLUMN_USERNAME like ‘%" +users+”%’”;

Here `COLUMN_USERNAME` is your `database column` and
`Users` is the `string` you want to search.

Comment: This is dangerous as user "tobias" will also be returned when you search for "tobi"

Comment: so would `String queryString = "SELECT " + COLUMN_USERNAME + " FROM " + ACCOUNT_TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_USERNAME + " = %" + user +"%";` be correct right?

Comment: No, the `%tobi%` will make `tobi`, `argtobi` and `tobias` return true

Comment: Just `=user` as in my answer

Comment: Use “like” operator instead of “=“

Comment: Is “user” the string you want to search in column_username?

Comment: yes it is, user is the string that is being passed from the function

Comment: If so use this query: “Where”+ column_name + “=‘user’”;